# Change span class content

Tags: css

Firstimer here. Sorry if myquestion is too stupid.

How can I change the label in :

```
<span class="fluid-thumbnail-grid-image-type">
XYZ
</span>
```

I want change XYZ to something else in a hosted application.
I have access only to add custom CSS to the head section.

Thanks in advance

Fernando

Comment: Can you edit the HTML as well?

Answer (score 0):

**CSS/HTML Solution:**
If you are able to edit the html, and want to use only CSS, you may use the `:before` (or `:after`) selector:

```css
.fluid-thumbnail-grid-image-type:before{
  content:"ZYX"
 }
```

```html
<span class="fluid-thumbnail-grid-image-type"></span>
```

**Javascript Solution:** If you are able to add javascript I would recommend jQuery `.html()` like so:

```js
$('.fluid-thumbnail-grid-image-type').html('ZYX');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="fluid-thumbnail-grid-image-type">XYZ</span>
```

Comment: @FernandoLopez You may mark mine as the correct answer iif you would like by clicking the gray checkbox/tick in the top left corner of my answer. The tick box shows up below the up/down vote counter.

Answer (score 0):

**Using only CSS** Here's what you can do >>>***[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Microsmsm/7owxg1ho/1/)*** Using CSS Pseudo-element `:after` and `content`

```css
.fluid-thumbnail-grid-image-type {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.fluid-thumbnail-grid-image-type:after {
  content: 'ABC';
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span class="fluid-thumbnail-grid-image-type">
XYZ
</span>
```

Comment: @Fernando Lopez ^_^ !